# Vercel serverless importing a common file

Tags: vercel

I'm struggling to import a common file. Here's my file structure:

```
 -> core (monorepo)
     -> **service1 (this hosts our serverless functions)**
          -> vercel.json
          -> api 
              -> handler1.ts (uses _common.ts)
              -> handler2.ts (uses _common.ts)
              -> _common.ts
     -> golang backend
     -> ...
```

Whenever I try to import `_common.ts` from either `handler1.ts` or `handler2.ts` I get the following:

> Cannot find module '/some_path/core/service1/api/_common' imported from /some_path/core/service1/api/handler1.ts